# Use Button to change value in datagridview cell and then save changes in SQL database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a dataGridVew1 on my windows form that I am populating from SQL using SQL Adapter named in my case "sda".
You can see how I update my grid below (maybe I am doing something wrong):

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string"); //defining connection
    con.Open(); 
    string sql_command = "Select * from Test_Table";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql_command, con); // defining the command
    DataSet set = new DataSet("SQL_table");
    SqlDataAdaptersda = new SqlDataAdapter(command); //defining the adapter and make it accept changes
        sda.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true; 
        sda.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        set.Clear(); //just to make sure my adapter is empty
    cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda); //creating the command builder so I can save the changes
        sda.Fill(set, "SQL_table");  // fill the dataset
        dataGridView1.DataSource = set; 
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "SQL_table"; //fill datagrid
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged; //look for cell value changed (I am using this in other scope)
```

When I manually change a value to any cell of the grid I use a button to save the changes to the database using:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sda.Update(set.Tables["SQL_table"]);
    }
```

It works perfectly.
I have added a second button to change a cell value in the datagrid for the selected row, but I have trouble saving those changes.

```
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) //I am checking to see if any row is selected
        {
            row_index = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index; //to get the selected row index

            this.dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[2].Value = "change"; //I am changing the cell text on column 2 on the selected row
            dataGridView1.EndEdit(); //added this to try an make it work

                sda.Update(set.Tables["SQL_table"]); //trying to update the database

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please first select the row with the quote that is awaiting feedback."); // in case no row is selected

    }
```

This does not save the data to the database. I also tried pressing the other save button afterward but no result, no data is saved in the database even if the value "changed" is visible in the grid.

I know I cannot put the save command in the CellValueChanged event because it does not take the last change. 
How can I make it work in a separate button as mentioned above? What I need is to:
1. Press the button - that changes the value of a cell
2. commit the changes in the database.

Thank you.
Danut

EDIT 1: on Bolu's request

I am using the CellValueChanged event to update a column in my datagrid when other cells are changed:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex < 13)
           {
               DateTime datetime_send = DateTime.Now;
               dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13].Value = datetime_send;
           }
    }
```

I tried putting the update in the event but it does not save, so I am using the separate button to call the database save. (but this is another story). Now I just want to save the changes that i do with button3, which is update one cells value and then save in the database.

Comment: if it's possible show us code in `dataGridView1_CellValueChanged`

Comment: I have edited my question and added the information you requested. But I want to be able to save the changes I make with button3 automatically. Right now those changes are not saved with the update line in the same button.

Comment: I will do a workaround until I find a solution. I will send the update directly to the database (an update query) instead of changing the grid and commit the changes. I still cannot find out why it does not work.